# String to enum using valueOf crashes with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum with String defined as below

```
public enum MyEnumType {
    PRIMARY("primary"),
    SECONDARY("secondary");

    private final String myEnumType;

    MyEnumType(String myEnumType) {
        this.myEnumType = myEnumType;
    }

    public boolean equalsType(String myOtherEnumType) {
        return myOtherEnumType != null && myEnumType.equals(myOtherEnumType);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.myEnumType;
    }
}
```

When I defined my enum with a string below

```
MyEnumType myEnumType = MyEnumType.valueOf("primary");
```

It crashes

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant HelloWorld.MyEnumType.primary
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at HelloWorld$MyEnumType.valueOf(HelloWorld.java:11)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:36)
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: `MyEnumType.valueOf("PRIMARY");`. Surely.

Comment: Is it possible to get the small cap (as per the string defined in the enum)? as actually the string passed in to setup the enum is per the small cap defined in the enum

Comment: No. You would need a `Map` for that. And that begins to defeat the point of using an `enum` in the first place...

Comment: @BoristheSpider Why would it defeat the purpose? It seems like a fairly usual requirement I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `MyEnumType.valueOf(x.toUpperCase())` to make it look up the upper case version.

e.g.

```
MyEnumType e = MyEnumValue.valueOf("primary".toUpperCase());
```

> Is it possible that I have a way to provide Secondary-Style, and it get to instantiate the enum that I want, without need to manually manipulate the string?

You can provide a mapping of alternative lookups.

```
static final Map<String, MyEnumType> altMap = new HashMap<>();
static {
   for (MyEnumType met : MyEnumType.values()) {
        altMap.put(met.myEnumType, met);
        // add more aliases as desired.
   }
}

public static MyEnumType lookup(String str) {
    MyEnumType met = altMap.get(str);
    return met == null ? valueOf(str) : met;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That would make the trick. But in case I would like to have `SECONDARY_STYLE("Secondary-Style");`... I would need to do more regular expression of replacement. Is it possible that I have a way to provide `Secondary-Style`, and it get to instantiate the enum that I want, without need to manually manipulate the string?

Comment: @Elye I have updated my answer.